# Exponential decay learning rate based on batches instead of epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, reinforcement-learning

I want to have adaptive learning rate based on time steps instead of epochs unlike most of the schedulers are based. I have a model as:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

class DQNagent:

    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.model = self.build_model()    # original model
        self.target_model = self.build_model()  # target model
        self.lr = 1e-2

    def build_model(self):
        
        x_in = layers.Input(shape=(self.step_size, self.state_size))
        x_out = layers.Dense(20, activation='relu')(x_in)
        output = layers.Dense(self.action_size, activation='linear')(x_out)
        
        self.learning_rate = CustomSchedule()
 
        opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(self.learning_rate)
        model = Model(inputs=x_in, outputs=output_y, name="DQN")
        model.compile(loss=['mse'], optimizer=opt)
    

        return model
```

and I want to make a scheduler as something like this:

```
class CustomSchedule:
  def __init__(self, lr=1e-2):
    super(CustomSchedule, self).__init__()
    self.lr = lr
    self.t = 0

  def __call__(self):
    self.t +=1
    if self.t % 100 ==0:
        self.lr /= 10

    return self.lr
```

and my main code without declaration of everything has something like this:

```
dqn = DQNagent(state_size, action_size)

for step in range(1000):
    states_all = np.array([[[0, 0, 1],[1,0,1], [0, -1, 1], [1,-1,1]]])
    Q_values =  dqn.model.predict(state_all)[0]
    
    # training
    batch = memory.sample(batch_size)
    batch_states = utils.get_states_user(batch) # assuming I have generated states using this method
    
    Q_states = dqn.model.predict(batch_states) # assuming I have sampled batch states
    
    dqn.model.fit(batch_states, Q_states, verbose =0)
```

I want to schedule my learning rate in a way that if my lets say `step%100==0` the learning rate is decreased as `learning_rate/10`. Seems like for the `CustomSchedule` class that I have created, I will have to recompiled the `model` which doesn't seem efficient to save and load weights. Is there any other way I can do this?

### EDITS:

I have edited my code as following @FedericoMalerba [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65526528/2252047)

Created a `decay_func` as:

```
def decay_func(step, lr):

    return lr/10**(step/100)
```

then I added followings changes to my `DQNAgent` class:

```
class DQNAgent():
     def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
     self.lr = 1e-2
     self.t_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name='Step', dtype=tf.int64)
     self.decaying_lr = partial(decay_func, step=self.step, lr=self.lr)
     
    def __call__(self):
        self.step.assign_add(1)
        return self.step
```

and called `dqn()` in my main code for every step. The callable `decaying_lr` is is passed to the optimiser in `build_model()` as
`opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(self.decaying_lr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general way to approach this would be to create a callable (a function) that takes no arguments and pass that to the Adam optimizer you define in `DQNagent.build_model()`. To do this follow these steps:

1. Create your epsilon decay function:

```
def decay_func(step_tensor, **other_arguments_your_func_needs):
    # body of the function. The input argument step tensor must be used
    # to determine the learning rate that will be returned
    return learning_rate
```

2. Create your step tensor (IT MUST BE A TENSOR!!!):

```
step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name='Step', dtype=tf.int64)
```

3. Create the callable to pass to the Optimizer:

```
from functools import partial

decaying_learning_rate = partial(decay_func, step_tensor=step, **other_arguments_your_func_needs)
```

4. Pass the callable when you create your optimizer:

```
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(decaying_learning_rate)
```

5. In your training loop iterate by increasing your step Tensor with:

```
step.assing_add(1)
```

What you are essentially doing is creating a callable `decaying_learning_rate` that takes no argument because all of the arguments have been given to it by the `functools.partial` call on it. The tensorflow optimizer will realize that the learning rate is not a number, but a callable and will call it like so:

```
this_step_learning_rate = decaying_learning_rate()
```

Since Tensors are shared objects across your runtime, when you increase your step counter with `step.assing_add(1)`, this new step will be used to compute the new learning rate in your `decay_func` at the next call that the optimizer does. This happens even though you are not explicitly passing the new and updated Tensor. MAGIC!

Btw, this is exactly what [Exponential Decay](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules/ExponentialDecay) does. The only thing I have presented here is a general way to define your own `decay_func` as you wish and how to have it work like the pre implemented exponential decay by TF.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I am looking for I think. I have made changes in the code following your answer. I hope it will work the intended way. Can you please check? Thanks

Comment: 3 things:

1) You absolutely should not change the code in the question, otherwise the question and the answer will not make sense to other people who come here in the future. Please revert the changes.

2) There is a typo in the `__call__` method. You wrote `self.step_assign_add(1)` instead of `self.step.assign_add(1)`

3) It's highly suboptimal that `decay_func` is a method of the agent because it means that you need to move around the agent class. Also I do not think this will work. Instead create `decay_func` as a standalone function and have it receive two arguments: `step` and ...

Comment: ... `learning_rate` then define the agent's `self.decaying_lr = partial(decay_func, step=self.step, learning_rate=self.lr)`. (you will need to define `self.lr` before this obviosuly)

Comment: Ok I am sorry about that. You're right. I have reverted the changes.

Comment: Wouldn't passing `self.lr` in `self.decaying_lr = partial(decay_func, step=self.step, learning_rate=self.lr)` pass the same value of `learning_rate` to `decay_func` everytime?

Comment: Oh yes, my bad, in that case you can either create a learning rate tensor that you pass to the function with partial or you can change your decay func to `return lr / 10**tf.floordiv(step, 100)`

Comment: I have also added changes in my answer under a separate EDIT heading

Comment: Hi, the `decay_func` returns a tensor and I am having problem saving my model (with `model.save`) because of this - I get this error `TypeError: ('Not JSON Serializable:', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.001>)`. I tried to convert it into `.numpy()`  but it says ```Tensor' object has no attribute numpy```. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Well I hope changing to numpy would solve as here [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28799)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [Exponential Decay](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules/ExponentialDecay). You can use this as learning rate:

```
initial_learning_rate = 0.1
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate,
    decay_steps=50,
    decay_rate=0.1,
    staircase=True)
```

Every 50 steps, starting at a learning rate of 0.1, the learning rate will be divided by 10.

Here is a working training script, and I printed the resulting learning rate. I made a custom callback so it prints the learning rate at the end of every batch.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

(xtrain, ytrain), _ = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

xtrain = np.float32(xtrain/255)
ytrain = np.int32(ytrain)

def pre_process(inputs, targets):
    inputs = tf.expand_dims(inputs, -1)
    targets = tf.one_hot(targets, depth=10)
    return tf.divide(inputs, 255), targets

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xtrain, ytrain)).\
    take(10_000).shuffle(100).batch(8).map(pre_process)

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dropout, Flatten

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                            strides=(1, 1), input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                            strides=(1, 1)),
    MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(5e-1),
    Dense(10)])


class PrintLRCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        print(model.optimizer.iterations.numpy(),
              model.optimizer._decayed_lr(tf.float32).numpy())

initial_learning_rate = 0.1
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate,
    decay_steps=50,
    decay_rate=0.1,
    staircase=True)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule))

history = model.fit(train_ds, verbose=0, 
                    callbacks=[PrintLRCallback()],
                    steps_per_epoch=250)
```

Every 10 iterations, I printed the iterations and learning rate:

```
10 0.1
20 0.1
30 0.1
40 0.1
50 0.01 
60 0.01 
70 0.01 
80 0.01 
90 0.01 
100 0.001
110 0.001
120 0.001
130 0.001
140 0.001
150 0.0001 
160 0.0001 
170 0.0001 
180 0.0001 
190 0.0001
```

Comment: I have seen such examples. Thank you. However, I  wanted a bit of help with my code I posted in question.

Comment: I meant how would I use it in my `build_model()` above

Comment: I try to make my answers as generalizable as possible, because the purpose of this site is not to assist users on 1v1 sessions, but to create a database of knowledge for future visitors. I'm afraid that tailoring my answer to your existing code would defeat that purpose. That being said, `optimizer` has a `.iterations` variable that you can use to reassign `.learning_rate` after compiling. Maybe try that

Comment: In `history = model.fit(train_ds, verbose=0, callbacks=[PrintLRCallback()], steps_per_epoch=250)`, what does `steps_per_epoch=250` mean? Does it mean each epoch is divided into 250 steps and the learning rate decay is for each epoch?

Comment: You can remove `steps_per_epoch`, it was for demonstrative purposes only. I wanted the epoch to stop after 250 batches were processed so I could move on with my life.